# Count number of records based on last updated date + null

Tags: sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

Having trouble with what I thought would be pretty simple.  Trying to get a count of items that don't have a title, our system tracks records by 'last_updated_date'.

```
id    work_item      title         last_updated_date  
1     task1          ProjectA      2020-03-25 20:20:01.111
2     task2          ProjectA      2020-03-25 20:20:01.111
3     task3                        2020-03-25 20:20:01.111
4     task4          ProjectB      2020-03-25 20:20:01.111
5     task5          ProjectC      2020-03-25 20:20:01.111
```

As you can see, I need to see what work items don't have a project.  If I were to look at the history for 'task1' I would see something like following:

```
select work_item, last_updated_date, project
from table
where work_item = 'task1'
```

This would output:

```
work_item      last_updated_date          title
task1          2020-03-25 20:20:01.111    ProjectA
task1          2020-03-17 20:20:01.111    NULL
task1          2020-03-12 20:20:01.111    NULL
```

Based on this, I can see that task1 got a title assigned on 2020-03-25.  What I need to know, is how many work items in the entire data set do not have a item assigned.  So I want to check all records using the last updated date and check the latest last_updated_date to see if title is null.  I tried the following, but I think I'm using MAX and/or group by wrong?  I'm getting records back that have titles assigned, which makes me think it's checking the MAX value of the entire last_updated_date column, rather than each record within.

```
select id, title, MAX(last_updated_date) as "latest_timestamp"
FROM table
WHERE title is null
group by id, title
```

What I would like to see is only task3 show up as needing a title assigned.

Comment: I see you got an acceptable answer, but you may also want to check out the last_value() window function in Snowflake.  This would completely avoid the sub-query:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a subquery to filter on the latest record per item. You can then count how many of them have no title:

```
select count(*)
from mytable t
where 
    last_updated_date = (
        select max(t1.last_updated_date) 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.work_item = t.work_item
    )
    and title is null
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by work_item order by last_updated_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1 and title is null
```

Comment: Wow, first one worked.  I did try a nested select but I put my conditions for the where clause before and not after.  Looks like I'm getting the right results now.